# Get SelectedText in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, getselection

I would like to understand how the getSelection function works. Therefore I want to do a little test. I want to display my selected text on a button.

My code:

```
<template name="seltext">
<textarea>This is a test test test test</textarea>
<input type="button" id="test"  class="new" value="pause">
</template>

Template.seltext.events({
  'click .new': function(){
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
      text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
      text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
    value = "text";
}});
```

I don't know why it doesn't work though, anyone any idea?

Comment: Why do you have `value = "text";` after returning a value? This code is never reached.

Comment: cause I want the button to display the selected text to see if it works. Is that not how you do it ?

Comment: No, that `value =` part will never be reached.  Perhaps you meant to put it within the object after the function: `{ 'click .new': function(){ ...}, value: "text" }`?   What templating engine are you using?

Comment: right, that's what I meant, I'm using meteor

Comment: ok - never used it before. ;)

Comment: hold on, but that still doesn't give me back the text. so I have  'return text; value : text;' now but it still doesn't work

Comment: If you are trying to set a global variable `value` to `text` then you need to delete `return text;` and change the `value = "text";` line to `value = text;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

selection is a Selection object. When cast to string, either by appending an empty string ("") or using String.toString(), this object is the text selected. This does not work with inputs or textareas.

Comment: ok, this makes sense, so if I use just normal headline or text, will it work then? But it still doesnt change when I click on the button

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, Joshua you were right about the object, thank you! Also the return makes the line after obsolete.

```
<template name="seltext">
This is a test test test test
<input type="button" id="test"  class="new" value="pause">
</template>

Template.seltext.events({
  'click .new': function(){
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
      text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
      text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    $('#test').prop('value', text);
}});
```